# How can I show my own message and then exit setup if the current version of Windows is not supported?

Tags: windows, version, inno-setup

I have to check if the Windows version is not lower than 6.1 which is Windows 7. If it is lower I need to show my own message and then exit setup.
If I write this in the `[Setup]` section:

```
[Setup]
MinVersion=6.1
```

the message that is shown is a standard one.
How can I show my own message and then exit setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Handling and customizing errors and messages in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65980371/850848).

This particular message is defined by the `WindowsVersionNotSupported` message.

You can change it in the [`[Messages]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=messagessection):

```
[Messages]
WindowsVersionNotSupported=You are using an ancient version of Windows.
```

[image]